# converting list of data frames into single data frame

Tags: r

I have created a function which is calculating mean and median for list of columns and converting it into list of tables for multiple column variables.

I have tried rbind, rbindlist, but nothing is working.

```
t1 <- do.call(rbind, table_list)
```

```
df <- mtcars

df1 <- subset(df, vs==1)
df2 <- subset(df, am==1)
df3 <- subset(df, gear==3)

df_list <- list(df1,df2,df3)
banner <- c("T1","T2","T3")


sub_fun<-function(db,var,var_name){
  var = rlang::parse_expr(var)
  
  df1<- db %>% filter(!is.na(!!var)) %>%   summarise(
    Median =quantile(!!var, type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)[3],
    Mean =  mean(!! var, na.rm=TRUE),
    N = sum(!is.na(!!var)))
  df<- df1 %>% mutate(" "=!!var_name,
                                       Median = Median,
                                       Mean = Mean,)
  df <- df %>% select(" ",everything(),N)
  df
  
  }
  
func1<-function(db,list_var,var_name_list,....){
  table_list1<-list()
  for (d in 1:length(df_list)) {
  
    table_list<-list()
    for (i in 1:length(list_var)) {
      
      
      table_list[[i]]<-sub_fun(db, list_var[i],var_name_list[i])
      
      t1 <- do.call(rbind,table_list)
      
    }
    
    colnames(t1)[1] <- banner[[d]]
    t1 <- t1 %>%
      add_row() %>%
      mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), ""))
    
    table_list1[[d]] <- t1
  }
#here the actual question is how i can convert the list of dataframes in table_list1 to single dataframe.
  t2 <- do.call(rbind,table_list1)
  t2
  
}

debug(func1)
func1(db=df,list_var=c("cyl","disp","hp"),var_name_list=c("klick","Nemar","Wingo"))
```

The output table t2 should be look like

[image]

Comment: yes this is R only

Comment: If you want to stack the data frames on top of each other and they share column names then use `bind_rows(df1,df2,df3)`

Comment: @JohnNielsen i want to make it dynamic for list table_list1

Comment: Is your expected output actually correct? This seems to be using the original `df = mtcars` for each iteration. Do you want each iteration to be for each respective element in `df_list`?

Comment: @Adam you can ignore the output , but the requirement is i am trying to paste list of tables in table_list1 . one after another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there is a better solution out there.
The problem you can't use `rbind` is because you have differing colnames (e.g. T1, T2, T3...)

So my idea was to name each df in the list with

```
  names(table_list1) <- banner
  Map(cbind, table_list1, SampleID = names(table_list1))
```

then add new names to each dataframe:

```
  colnames <- c("name","Median","Mean", "N") 
  
  for (i in seq_along(table_list1)){
    colnames(table_list1[[i]]) <- colnames
  }
```

Now you can use your code:

```
  t2 <- do.call(rbind,table_list1)
  t2
```

```
func1<-function(db,list_var,var_name_list,....){
  table_list1<-list()
  for (d in 1:length(df_list)) {
    
    table_list<-list()
    for (i in 1:length(list_var)) {
      
      
      table_list[[i]]<-sub_fun(db, list_var[i],var_name_list[i])
      
      t1 <- do.call(rbind,table_list)
      
    }
    
    colnames(t1)[1] <- banner[[d]]
    t1 <- t1 %>%
      add_row() %>%
      mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), ""))
    
    table_list1[[d]] <- t1
  }
  names(table_list1) <- banner
  Map(cbind, table_list1, SampleID = names(table_list1))
  
  
  colnames <- c("name","Median","Mean", "N") 
  
  for (i in seq_along(table_list1)){
    colnames(table_list1[[i]]) <- colnames
  }
  
  t2 <- do.call(rbind,table_list1)
  t2
}
```

```
  name Median       Mean  N
T1.1 klick      6     6.1875 32
T1.2 Nemar  196.3 230.721875 32
T1.3 Wingo    123   146.6875 32
T1.4                           
T2.1 klick      6     6.1875 32
T2.2 Nemar  196.3 230.721875 32
T2.3 Wingo    123   146.6875 32
T2.4                           
T3.1 klick      6     6.1875 32
T3.2 Nemar  196.3 230.721875 32
T3.3 Wingo    123   146.6875 32
T3.4
```

Comment: what is we want to keep or have column names t1  rather than updating again like below...???                      
colnames <- c("name","Median","Mean", "N") 
  
  for (i in seq_along(table_list1)){
    colnames(table_list1[[i]]) <- colnames
  }

Answer (score 1):

Use `do.call` :

```
df <- mtcars

df1 <- subset(df, vs==1)
df2 <- subset(df, am==1)
df3 <- subset(df, gear==3)

df_list <- list(df1,df2,df3)
do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Comment: this is working but my function is not working what i am doing wrong in my function